# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

If I try to log into my app with postman, I get an error on the indicated line:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

```php
private $client;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = Client::find(1);
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    return $this->issueToken($request, 'password');
}

public function issueToken(Request $request, $grantType, $scope = "")
{
    $params = [
        'grant_type' => $grantType,
        'client_id' => $this->client->id, // this line has error
        'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,           
        'scope' => $scope
    ];

    if($grantType !== 'social'){
        $params['username'] = $request->username ?: $request->email;
    }

    $request->request->add($params);
    $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');
    return Route::dispatch($proxy);
}
```

Why am I getting this error message?

---

Note, on newer versions of PHP, this error will show as:

> "Attempt to read property "id" on null

Comment: This means `$this->client` is `null`

Comment: Sorry i forgot it.added $client variable

Comment: show dd($this->client)

Comment: null @Sohel0415 How to i fill $this->client. I learn laravel with a video.And i apply same operation with video.What's wrong?

Comment: do you have client with id 1??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The error is because `$this->client` is null when `find()` cannot find the record.

You need to be sure if the record exists or not.

**Change:**

```
$this->client = Client::find(1);
```

**To:**

```
$this->client = Client::findOrFail(1);
```

**Documentation:**

From [Laravel Eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent), 
this will throw a `404` error if no record with the specified id is found.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have record in database table for User model with id = 1. When you're using User::find(1) Laravel tries to get this record from database, if record is absent this will return null

Comment: check oauth_clients table and check record id 1, it must exist for it to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

In your `issueToken()` method-

```
$client = Client::find(1);
if($client!=null){
     $params = [
       'grant_type' => $grantType,
       'client_id' => $client->id,
       'client_secret' => $client->secret,           
       'scope' => $scope
    ];
}else{
    $params = [
       'grant_type' => $grantType,
       'client_id' => null,
       'client_secret' => null,           
       'scope' => $scope
    ];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I was trying access an id which doesn't exist in my project database. This `$user= user::findOrFail($id);` solved my problem.