# Laravel: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: laravel

this is my code and i dont know where is the problem
$evaluationjob = evaluation_elements_jobs::where('job_id', $user->job_id)->
first();

```
    if($evaluationjob !==null && isset($evaluationjob["element_degree"]))
    {
      $items = json_decode($evaluationjob["element_degree"]);
    }
  

    $evaluation_keies = [];

    foreach ($items as $index => $item)
    {

       $key = evaluation_element::where('id',$index)->where('status',0)->first();
                 //error in the above line
        $reuslt["id"] = $key->id;
        $reuslt["title"] = $key->title
```

Comment: what is the error message that you get?

Comment: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object when i write this code
       $key = evaluation_element::where('id',$index)->where('status',0)->first();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.5 Trying to get property 'id' of non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422199/laravel-5-5-trying-to-get-property-id-of-non-object)

Answer (score 0):

Check if `key` is an object before access the attributes, I think your query is not returning records then null is returned.

```
$key = evaluation_element::where('id',$index)->where('status',0)->first();


if(!is_null($key)) {
    $reuslt["id"] = $key->id;
    $reuslt["title"] = $key->title
}
```

Comment: thank you very much iam write your code and run successfuly

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, I would like to advise you to use the `firstOrFail()` method and `Eloquent local scopes`.
From the official [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquen):

**[Not Found Exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions)**

> The `findOrFail` and `firstOrFail` methods will retrieve the first result
> of the query; however, if no result is found, an
> `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown:

```
$key = evaluation_element::where('id',$index)->where('status',0)->firstOrFail();
```

**[Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes)**:

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include items with status is 0.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return void
 */
public function scopeInActive($query)
{
    $query->where('status', 0);
}
```

Usage scopes:

```
$key = evaluation_element::where('id',$index)->inActive()->firstOrFail();
```