# Laravel Attempt to read property "Username" on null

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel, and I keep running into this error:

> Attempt to read property "Username" on null

I have made a custom login form, with correct validation, and even a success message when the user is logged in correctly. However, any time that I try to use @auth or, more specifically, Auth::user(), nothing gets dispalyed, with no errors either.

I don't understand how I can successfully login, and yet every time I try to call upon the logged in information, it appears null, or just non-existent.

If I try to even output simple `@auth <p>Hello world</p> @endauth` the webpage works perfectly without the auth, but does not display anything inside of the @auth. Of course, it also appears with no errors.

My theory is that instead of using Auth::attempt() I found the user using the raw username and password and logged them in that way.

I simply want to display a logged in's Username by displaying:

```html
{{ Auth::user()->Username }}
```

I am open to any and all suggestions.

Here is my main controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\login;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\New_UserModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class Signup_NewController extends Controller
{
    function NewUser_homePost(Request $request)
    {
        // grabs Username and Password
        $user = New_UserModel::where([
            'Username' => $request->Username,
            'Password' => $request->Password
        ])->first();

        // Checks to see if user is authenticated or not
        if($user)
        {
            // Logs in the user
            Auth::login($user);
            return redirect(route('User_Home'))->with("success", "Logged in successfully");
        }

        return redirect(route('Home'))->with("error", "Login details are not valid");
    }

    public function New_HomePage() {
        // ONLY DISPLAYS Register if users are not logged in
        if(Auth::check()) {
            return redirect(route('home'));
        }
        return view('login.New_Home');
    }

    public function createPost(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'Username' => 'required',
            'Password' => 'required',
            'Email' => 'required|email|unique:new_user',
        ]);

        $data['First_Name'] = $request->First_Name;
        $data['Last_Name'] = $request->Last_Name;
        $data['Phone'] = $request->Phone;
        $data['Email'] = $request->Email;
        $data['Add1'] = $request->Add1;
        $data['Add2'] = $request->Add2;
        $data['Zip'] = $request->Zip;
        $data['City'] = $request->City;
        $data['State'] = $request->State;
        $data['Username'] = $request->Username;
        $data['Password'] = $request->Password;

         // Saving to database
         $user = New_UserModel::create($data);

         if(!$user)
         {
             return redirect(route('Home'))->with("error", "Registration failed");
         }

         // Displays post created on button click
         return redirect(route('New_Home'))->with('success', 'Post as been created');
    }

     // LOGOUT
     function logout()
     {
         Session::flush();
         Auth::logout();
         return redirect(route('Home'))->with('success', "Logged out");
     }
}
```

Here is my modal if that helps:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class New_UserModel extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $guarded=[];

    protected $fillable = [
        'Username',
        'Password'
    ];

    protected $table = "new_user";

}
```

Also, here are my Routes:

```php
Route::get('/New_Home', [Signup_NewController::class, 'New_Homepage'])
    ->name('New_Home');

// Creating new accounts
Route::post('/create-post', [Signup_NewController::class, 'createPost'])
    ->name('post.create');


Route::get('/login', [Signup_NewController::class, 'login'])
    ->name('login');

// Login Logic
Route::post('/user_login', [Signup_NewController::class, 'NewUser_homePost'])
    ->name('NewUser.post');

Route::get('/logout', [Signup_NewController::class, 'logout'])
    ->name('logout');
```

Comment: Hey, did you change your model on config -> auth.php -> providers ->model?

Comment: Hi! I suggest you to only include the relevant code so it's easier for others to help you.

Comment: I did not. I am new to Laravel. What would the config file do?

Comment: it's going to use the new model (New_UserModel.php ), instead of the default User model (User.php) to get the users data

Comment: You should **NEVER** store raw unencrypted user passwords in your database.  This is a huge security hole. 

Comment: Please read, [Laravel: Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to get property 'id' of non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422199/trying-to-get-property-id-of-non-object)

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're experiencing may be related to the way you're logging in the user. In Laravel, when you use Auth::login($user), you need to make sure that the user instance is an instance of Laravel's authenticatable User model, and it should have been retrieved using the authentication driver, which uses the user's credentials to retrieve the user instance.

However, you're querying the database directly using the raw username and password and getting an instance of the user that way. This may cause the application to not set the user in Laravel's authentication session properly.

Instead of querying the user with raw username and password, use Auth::attempt() method to authenticate the user. Auth::attempt() takes an array of credentials and log the user in if they are valid.

Example:

```
function NewUser_homePost(Request $request) 
{
    // Validate the request data
    $credentials = $request->only('Username', 'Password');

    // Attempt to login
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect(route('User_Home'))->with("success", "Logged in successfully");
    }

    // Authentication failed...
    return redirect(route('Home'))->with("error", "Login details are not valid");
}
```

Make sure that your User model (in this case New_UserModel) uses the appropriate fields for authentication. By default, Laravel uses email for the username and password for the password. If you are using a different column name for the username, like Username in your case, make sure you've customized the authentication to use that.

I recommend using the default laravel User model.
Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT, which is banned on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It nearly works. I went into my config\auth.php and modified the model and table name. However, I keep getting this Undefined array key "password" whenever I try to login. I guess the username is being read, but for whatever reason the password doesnt seem to be registering

Comment: @JohnLyons Can you add the html to the post? Is Password in the $request variable? If you dd($request)